# Using migrations to delete table with foreign key

Tags: laravel, laravel-4

I am trying to roll back my migrations.

My migrations file uses foreign keys like so:

```
$table->foreign('user_one')->references('id')->on('users');
$table->foreign('user_two')->references('id')->on('users');
```

My down() function is like so:

```
public function down()
{
    Schema::drop('pm_convo');
    Schema::drop('pm_convo_replys');
}
```

When I run my migrate command:

```
php artisan migrate:refresh --seed --env=local
```

I am getting the following error:

```
SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1217 Cannot delete or update a parent row: a foreign key constraint fails (SQL: drop table `pm_convo`)
```

I am not exactly sure what to do to fix this.

I have tried: `$table->dropForeign('pm_convo_user_one_foreign');`, but I am getting errors with that as well.

Comment: Do you have another table that has a foreign key that references to `pm_convo`?

Comment: Yes i do .. Theres a table called pm_convo_replys which has $table->foreign('c_id_fk')->references('id')->on('pm_convo');

Comment: In that case, turn the two `drop` calls around.

Comment: Your kidding hahaha i been searching that for hours ... Thank you!!!!

Answer (score 76, accepted):

`pm_convo_replys` has a foreign key that references `pm_convo`, thus you **cannot delete `pm_convo` first** without violating a foreign key constraint in `pm_convo_replys`.

To delete both you need to **delete `pm_convo_replys` first**.

```
public function down()
{
    Schema::drop('pm_convo_replys');
    Schema::drop('pm_convo');
}
```

Answer (score 93):

I think this is a better way to do it:

```
public function down()
{
    DB::statement('SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS = 0');
    Schema::dropIfExists('tableName');
    DB::statement('SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS = 1');
}
```

Comment: This is an easier way to do this for sure if you have a lot of foreign keys to deal with but will this work with all types of database? Also would it not be possible during development if your migrations aren't quite right to accidentally leave foreign key checks off? Personally I feel its cleaner just to order them correctly

Comment: Thx, this solution has solved my problem with a truncate on my database seed.

Comment: I think it is unwise to use `dropIfExists` here. In principle, I find it is better to write migrations that rely on the current state of the database being what you think it is. If the state of the database is different from what you expect when the `down` function is run (say the table doesn't exist), then chances are there is something terribly wrong with your `up` function, and you really need to fix that first.

Comment: Turning off `SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS` momentarily feels like a hack, but given that a foreign constraint was made on my db with a clear name in the migrations...this is the best answer for some situations. +1

Comment: SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS is only applicable to that session. It doesn't disable foreign key checking indefinitely on the server. Therefore it's not as dangerous as it sounds, however there is obviously still a threat to the integrity of your data if you don't use it carefully.

Comment: Schema::disableForeignKeyConstraints(); Schema::drop('table_child');Schema::drop('table_parent');Schema::enableForeignKeyConstraints(); According manual. For Laravel 5.2

Answer (score 42):

I also faced these kind of issues. Migration file order is the main issue here. The best way is to create migration files one by one. Main entities should be created first. Migration should be refreshed with every migrate file creation. (with `php artisan migrate:refresh`)

According to @abkrim and @Eric

```
public function down()
{
    Schema::disableForeignKeyConstraints();
    Schema::drop('tableName');
    Schema::enableForeignKeyConstraints();
}
```

Comment: Cleaner code than `DB::statement('SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS = 0');`

Comment: do you need to enable the foreign key constraint again? what if i comment enableForeignKeyConstraints();

Answer (score 15):

I think this is the most correct approach:

```
public function down()
{
    Schema::table('[table]', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->dropForeign('[table]_[column]_foreign');
        $table->dropColumn('[column]');
    });
}
```

Comment: I totally agree with you: this is the correct steps' order. This should be the accepted answer.

Comment: Will this trigger `ON DELETE`?

Answer (score 3):

prefer to do it this way

```
    Schema::dropIfExists('tableNameChild');
    Schema::drop('tableNameParents');
```

Answer (score 2):

**Important, this is for Laravel 5.4**.

According to the [docs](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/migrations#indexes)

> To drop a foreign key, you may use the dropForeign method. Foreign key constraints use the same naming convention as indexes. So, we will concatenate the table name and the columns in the constraint then suffix the name with **"_foreign"**

```
$table->dropForeign('posts_user_id_foreign');
```

> Or, you may pass an array value which will automatically use the conventional constraint name when dropping:

```
$table->dropForeign(['user_id']);
```

I personally prefer the second one because of simplicity

Answer (score 2):

You can do that thing very easily if you added `cascade` on the `foeign key` when creating the table. If you did it, then you can remove the table very easily without something like this for PostgreSQL.

```
DB::statement("drop table if exists tableName cascade");
```

All you have to do is to put the statement for SQL table in the raw format.

Comment: That should be `DB::statement("drop table if exists tableName cascade");`.

Comment: Thank you. Didn't notice it.