# Sprint Transaction Management - Delete tables with foreign key constraint gives DataIntegrityViolationException

Tags: spring, spring-transactions

I have two tables (table 1 and table 2).
Table 2 is having table 1's primary key as its foreign key.
When I am trying to delete table 2, I am getting DataIntegrityViolationException.

```
@Transactional
methodToDelete(){
  deleteTable1();
  deleteTable2();
}
```

Can someone please help me in fixing this issue?

Comment: Delete the table2 first.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Using migrations to delete table with foreign key](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17108671/using-migrations-to-delete-table-with-foreign-key)

Comment: In Spring transaction management, the delete will get commit only when the control comes out of the method. So in this case, even if i try to delete table 2 first, it will not get commit, and then table 1 delete will be called. It will give data integrity violation. If i commit table 2 deletion before calling table 1 deletion, then i can't roll back in case if some unexpected error occurs while executing table 1 deletion process.